# search empty value in awk

Tags: awk

I have a txt file which has many columns whcih are pipe delimited. I want to check if column `$36` is '0', null or blank then filter the whole row.

```
awk -F"|" 'BEGIN{OFS="|"} NR!=1, $3="A" && $36!=0 && length($36)>0
{print $1, $81, $3, $2, $21, $22, $6, $19, $20, $25, $26, $29, $30,
$31, $33, $34, $36, $38, "", $39, "", "", $40, $42, "rrr", "", "" }'
```

I tried using `length($36)>0` but its not working for blank values. I can see the file the column is like this `||`(two pipes nothing in between).

Please help me to identify these values and apply the filter.

Answer (score 1):

Use `$36 ~ /^$|0/` to filter zero or empty string.

Comment: its not removing the blank values ||(two pipes nothing in between).
is it a possibility that there is some value in between which i can not see?

Answer (score 1):

You can filter is by using this condition:

```
awk -F '|' '($36 ~ /^0?$/)' file
```

Comment: its not removing the blank records

Comment: Can you try: `awk -F '|' '( $36 ~ /^ *$|0/ )' file`

Answer (score 1):

You could probably simplify the code a little by using more vertical space.  You have a comma in your condition which is puzzling; I think it should probably be a `&&`.  As shown, you have a condition without an action (so there's a default action of print `$0`), and an action without a condition (so there's a default match of every line).

```
awk -F"|" 'BEGIN{OFS="|"}
    NR != 1 && $3 = "A" && $36 != 0 && length($36) > 0 {
       print $1, $81, $3, $2, $21, $22, $6, $19, $20, $25, $26, $29, $30,
             $31, $33, $34, $36, $38, "", $39, "", "", $40, $42, "rrr", "", ""
    }'
```

Note that the `{` is on the same line as the condition.  Personally, I'd probably write it as:

```
awk -F"|" 'BEGIN{OFS="|"}
    {
        if (NR != 1 && $3 = "A" && $36 != 0 && length($36) > 0)
        {
            print $1, $81, $3, $2, $21, $22, $6, $19, $20, $25, $26, $29, $30,
                  $31, $33, $34, $36, $38, "", $39, "", "", $40, $42, "rrr", "", ""
        }
    }'
```

Thus far, I'm assuming that you want to print if it isn't the first row of data, if `$3` is `A`, and if `$36` is neither empty nor zero.  You say 'I want to filter', but that doesn't explain whether you want to include or exclude the filtered rows.  If you are only concerned with rows where field 36 is empty, you can simplify the condition to:

```
awk -F"|" 'BEGIN{OFS="|"}
    {
        if (NR != 1 && $3 = "A" && $36 != "")
        {
            print $1, $81, $3, $2, $21, $22, $6, $19, $20, $25, $26, $29, $30,
                  $31, $33, $34, $36, $38, "", $39, "", "", $40, $42, "rrr", "", ""
        }
    }'
```

Or you could use just `length($36) > 0` instead; they're equivalent in this context.

Given that you've not supplied any sample data and I can't be bothered to work out what a record with 81 or more pipe-separated fields looks like, I can't test this code.  When asking a question, you should simplify your code; you could make do with 4 columns, say, in an example, and then adapt the small-scale solution back to your real-world case with 80+ columns.

Answer (score 1):

```
$36 !~ /^[0 ]*$/
```

should do what you want, but it does not match if the entry has a zero value (eg `0.0`).  For that, try

```
$36 && $36 !~ /^[0 ]*$/
```